# npm install java: error MSB4019: The imported project "D:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found

Tags: java, node.js, npm, bridge, node-java

We are trying to use the node java bridge to run a java application..

As mentioned in the requirement we have to install the java in the node project.

so i am running the

> npm install java

I have already run the below command suggested in many forum like

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools
npm install -g nw-gyp
```

Getting below exception.

> PS D> npm install java
>
> java@0.10.0 install D:\nodebrigde\node_modules\java
>   node-gyp rebuild

```
D:\\nodebrigde\node_modules\java>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\no
de_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
D:\nodebrigde\node_modules\java\build\nodejavabridge_bindings.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "D:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Co
nfirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\nodebrigde\node_modules\java
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! java@0.10.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the java@0.10.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-25T10_03_58_299Z-debug.log
```

If possible please suggest in detail as i am new to angular/node

Answer (score 2):

Written initially in March 2020 for windows.

1. Run:

   npm install --global --production windows-build-tools@4.0.0
2. Add environment variable called "VCTargetsPath"
   with value of the path to folder of Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props. On my computer it is "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v140".
3. try downloading package again

===

**Edit:**

I have come to know this may be solved by giving node the path to python. (I don't think the version matters?). Try running:

```
npm config set python path\to\file\python.exe
```

Comment: after following the above steps, restarting the pc did the trick